# Find Phillips Hue Bridge in Production Web App on Other Network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, philips-hue

I am using the node-hue-api package on an Node.js/Express server to work with the Hue API. I've built an admin section of a website that only I can access that I'd like to use to control my Hue lights. This works fine in my dev environment as my localhost is obviously running on the same network/IP as the Bridge.

*I think* the problem is that when I push my changes to my production environment -- which is running on a Digital Ocean droplet of a different IP that the Bridge isn't connected to or aware of, it obviously can't find the Bridge -- returns empty array as response: `Hue Bridges Found: []`

I can't be the first to have this problem, but the documentation for Hue in general is sparse. I'm already doing both UPnP and N-UPnP searches, but I've seen mentions of doing an IP scan where you can set a specific IP to look for (I know the IP), but documentation for that is practically non-existent. Any ideas?

Since docs are sparse and this is close to working, here's the useful parts of my code in case it helps others or shows I'm doing something wrong.

```
hue    = require("node-hue-api");

//===== Hue =====

var HueApi = require("node-hue-api").HueApi,
    lightState = hue.lightState,
    timeout = 5000;

var displayResult = function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
};

var displayError = function(err) {
    console.error(err);
};

var displayBridges = function(bridge) {
    console.log("Hue Bridges Found: " + JSON.stringify(bridge));
};

hue.nupnpSearch().then(displayBridges).done();
hue.upnpSearch(timeout).then(displayBridges).done();

var hostname = "my-ip-address",
    username = "my-registered-user-hash",
    api = new HueApi(hostname, username),
    state = lightState.create(),
    lightsObject;

//Get all lights attached to the bridge
api.lights(function(err, lights) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lightsObject = lights;
    displayResult(lightsObject);
    console.log(lightsObject);
});
```

I then pass the lightsObject to my admin page through the render function, do a for loop to loop through each light in the returned object, then show some toggle switches based on the state in the object. Then `onchange`, I run a jQuery AJAX call to the app.put method here, which runs the node-hue-api code to set the light's state, passing the lightId from the value attribute of the toggle from the admin page. Here's a pic to show that working.

[image: Hue UI]

And the `app.put` code. Could probably combine these, but I wanted separate calls in case I want to do something more creative with the on state.

```
app.put('/lighton', function(req, res) {
    //Set the state of the light
    api.setLightState(req.body.lightId, state.on())
        .fail(displayError)
        .done();
});

app.put('/lightoff', function(req, res) {
    //Set the state of the light
    api.setLightState(req.body.lightId, state.off())
        .fail(displayError)
        .done();
});
```

Comment: Do you have a server in your home network that you could ssh to from the droplet? In that case, you could set up an SSH tunnel. Or perhaps your internet modem/router at home supports incoming VPN's, which you could connect to from DO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [FAQs in the Phillips Hue API documentation pages](http://www.developers.meethue.com/faq-page):

> *Where is the API located?*
>
> The hue API in the bridge is accessible on your local network. That is
>   to say, **it is accessible on your local WiFi or wired network and
>   cannot be accessed directly outside that network**. This also makes your
>   hue system secure. The hue bridge, once installed on your network,
>   will have its own IP address set up by your local router. This is the
>   IP address you will use when sending commands to the RESTful API.
>
> ...
>
> *Can I get remote access to hue (e.g. other than IFTTT)?*
>
> It is planned that we will have a remote API for accessing hue across
>   the Internet. **For now the only option available is to use the IFTTT
>   interface.**

(emphasis added)

So you'll either need to expose some custom API of your creation on your home server, or use IFTTT (I believe a maker channel could do what you want here, but I've not worked with one before so am not really sure), if this FAQ is to be believed.

Comment: For future answer seekers, I used maker.ifttt.com to set up a Recipe (Maker triggering Hue) for each of my lights, then plugged in the Maker web request URL into my existing AJAX request. The Maker Applet is imperfect as I can't get the light's active state and it takes about 6 seconds to respond as opposed to the Hue API's <1 second, but for the purposes of my site, it will do. In addition, I ripped out all the node-hue-api code from my production server, but chose to keep it in my dev env. Currently using it with a fs.writeFile to update a JSON file to use as a fallback. Hope this helps.